# Rails Custom ActionForm Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, actionform

I do not like the current date helper for action form and would like to replace it with something like the bootstrap datetime control.

I need to know the steps to write a custom actionform helper.  I need this because I am looking to make this a modular solution for date/time control that I can use across projects -- and share with the world too, of course.

I am relatively new to ruby/rails and the whole DSL thing... so please try to explain a little of the magic to a long time c/java programmer.

Comment: You may want to have a quick look into some other alternatives - I've found the [jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) very useful.

Comment: Thanks @Matt.  I would still like some general idea on how to write a custom actionform helper.